# passkit - pass not refreshing via push notification. (Server response was malformed)

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit

I have successfully integrated passkit but I am facing issue when updating passbook via push notification.
Notification successfully received to wallet but pass not updated.

Following are steps which I have implemented:

1. Used XMPP server (PHP).
2. used this library in php to generate pass (https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass). I have replaced pass type and team identifier.
3. Swift code to add pass to wallet. Pass successfully created and add to wallet.
4. To refresh pass "pull to refresh" is working in wallet app.

Here is my full code (PHP + SWIFT):
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e3wk8bwqgv8zs3f/AACZa_x7vD8KByl6WdrrgNExa?dl=0

Here are some logs:

1. While creating pass: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j14zfudy9mbllmp/add%20card.png?dl=0
2. Add card on wallet : -https://www.dropbox.com/s/yek9rf8js45p8xb/add%20card%20to%20wallet.png?dl=0
3. Pull to refresh two request from wallet app https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1sfpxfbqlwwu6q/pull%20to%20refresh%20request%201.png?dl=0
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jall5xmxpx806o/pull%20to%20refresh%20request%202.png?dl=0
4. when push notification received, two request from wallet:
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/sg3v9sgyu0w1e3n/push%20request%201.png?dl=0
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd2us3771f2xn3s/push%20request%202.png?dl=0

The error is **Server response was malformed...**

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you get hold of the raw bundle - you have 2 different content lengths 381636 on the pull and 381635 on the push.

Comment: I generating new bundle every time for pull and push. I have not noticed that content lengths. Is 1 byte difference may cause the issue?
Have you see the error "Server response was malformed... etc etc" ?

Comment: Hello @Parimal,
Would you help me for update pass from admin panel? 
We have added pass successfully to apple wallet but while updating we have received an error. 
Log from Server Log file.

{"logs":["[2018-09-25 11:50:09 +0530] Get serial #s task (for device 49deeaee707d67dbb44ac89480a58124, pass type PASSIDHERE, last updated (null); with web service url http:\/\/pass.abc.com\/admin\/mypkpass\/devices) encountered error: Server response was malformed (The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)"]}

Comment: @Parimal Here we facing the same issue, kindly help us to resolve the issue

 {"logs":["[2023-09-12 15:23:26 +1000]] Get serial #s task (for device 49deeaee707d67dbb44ac89480a58124, pass type PASSIDHERE, last updated (null); with web service url http:\/\/pass.abc.com\\/passes\\\/updatepass) encountered error: Server response was malformed

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this my self.
The problem was in 'Last-Modified' header date format.

It should be `header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));` in PKPass.php file

I received push notification and my pass is now updated automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: im having same issue can you please help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838318/apple-wallet-not-auto-updating-pass?noredirect=1#comment76770558_44838318

Comment: Hey! Sure. Post your details to understand.

Comment: do you mind helping me? I'm using most the same resource, not swift though. I have a server page - the passes generated separately. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981359/apple-wallet-passkit-pass

Comment: In my case, error was in Last-Modified format. Correct format is header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));