# PKPass error "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid."

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, passbook

Get the error

> BOM could not extract archive: Couldn't read PKZip signature
>
> Error Optional(Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass
> cannot be read because it isn’t valid."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1570e200 {Error
> Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"},
> NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn’t
> valid.})

check this code

```
var myPass : PKPass?

self.myPass = PKPass(data: pageData, error: &errorPass)
```

This is my code

```
   if PKPassLibrary.isPassLibraryAvailable()
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let pageData = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL(string: mainURL)!)
                    
                    var errorPass : NSError?
                    self.myPass = PKPass(data: pageData, error: &errorPass)
                    
                    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.mainScrollview, animated: true)
                    if errorPass == nil
                    {
                        let passview = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: self.myPass!)
                        passview.delegate = self
                        self.present(passview, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Error \(errorPass)")
                    }
                    
                    
                } catch let e as NSError {
                    print(e.localizedDescription)
                    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.mainScrollview, animated: true)
                    self.view.makeToast("Something went wrong with error : \(e.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
```

And my PKPass Format is

```
{
        "formatVersion" : 1,
        "passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.com.pek.pek",
        "serialNumber" : "'.$booking_id.'",
        "teamIdentifier" : "ABC00001",
        "webServiceURL" : "https://peek.com/ba/pass/",
        "authenticationToken" : "kjghadsfgghjgjhfadisfgyfgdsyfuya",
        
        "barcode" : {
          "message" : "123456789",
          "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
          "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
        },
        "organizationName" : "Peek Inc.",
        "description" : "Room",
        "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        "backgroundColor" : "rgb(0, 200, 83)",
        "eventTicket" : {
          "primaryFields" : [
            {
              "key" : "event",
              "label" : "Name",
              "value" : "'.$restaurant_name.'"
            }
          ],
              "secondaryFields" : [
            {
              "key" : "eventtime",
              "label" : "Date",
              "value" : "'.$slot_date.'"
            }
          ],
              "auxiliaryFields" : [
            {
              "key" : "bookingid",
              "label" : "BOOKING ID",
              "value" : "'.$booking_id.'"
            },
            {
              "key" : "noofperson",
              "label" : "NO OF TICKETS",
              "value" : "'.$no_of_tickets.'",
              "textAlignment" : "PKTextAlignmentCenter"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to download the PKPASS file and unzip it directly, just to check the file is zipped and packaged correctly?

Comment: Have you taken you PKPass format and compiled it into a signed, zipped, .pkpass bundle?  The data that you pass into the PKPass function should be a pass bundle (which is a zip file with a .pkpass extension)

Comment: yes i will @PassKit

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on PKPass and facing another issue. but I mention all step here to generate pass and update pass via pull to refresh and via push notification.  [steps...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668916/passkit-pass-not-refreshing-via-push-notification-server-response-was-malfor?noredirect=1)

Hope this helps!