# Apple Wallet Not Auto Updating Pass

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, apns-php, wallet, passkit

Finally im able to push new changed compiled bundle. There is one issue im facing in order to see new changes. i have to go in my wallet card & disable "Automatic updates" then enable. 
then i can see my new compiled pass card.

```
 $result = $pdo->query($query);

if($result->rowCount() > 0) {

    $myPass = $result->fetch();

    $data = $myPass['data'];
    $nameFile = 'passbook_'.time().'.pkpass';
    file_put_contents($nameFile, $data);

    $stream = function () use ($nameFile) {
        readfile($nameFile);
    };

    return $app->stream($stream, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass',
        'Content-length' => filesize($nameFile),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="passbook.pkpass"',
        'Last-Modified' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T')
    ));
```

compiled pass = `$myPass['data'];`.

please advice what im missing here.

2nd issue how can i show new updates in lock screen ?
i think i have to send this but little confuse where should i add this line in "pass.json" ? or should i send this in push notification?.

`{ "key":"header", "value":"More discount 50% off", "changeMessage": "%@" }`

Device logs: Iphone 4 IOS 9.3.5

```
 `Jul  5 06:51:30 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: Tracking com.apple.Passbook (via activity)
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone assertiond[64] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: assertiond + 22255 [490D29F9-F790-3C02-B1F0-75F21A182589]: 0x16
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone Unknown[64] <Error>: 
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone assertiond[64] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: assertiond + 22255 [490D29F9-F790-3C02-B1F0-75F21A182589]: 0x16
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone Unknown[64] <Error>: 
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x936d]' exited voluntarily.
Jul  5 06:51:37 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 5194416385: id=com.apple.mobilesafari pid=172, state=0
Jul  5 06:51:55 iPhone Passbook[178] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
Jul  5 06:51:56 iPhone ABLE[136] <Warning>: Current charge is 89.000000
Jul  5 06:52:02 iPhone locationd[69] <Warning>: PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {
    } cannot continue due to nils!
Jul  5 06:52:02 iPhone locationd[69] <Warning>: PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {
    } cannot continue due to nils!
Jul  5 06:53:54 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Jul  5 06:53:54 iPhone backboardd[63] <Notice>: [HID] [MT] MTSimpleHIDManager::setPropertyInternal detection mode: 3->255 
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone wirelessproxd[50] <Notice>: (Error) updateScanner - central is not powered on: 4
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: _UIGraphicsDrawIntoImageContextWithOptions: cannot draw into NULL context
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: _UIGraphicsDrawIntoImageContextWithOptions: cannot draw into NULL context
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: _UIGraphicsDrawIntoImageContextWithOptions: cannot draw into NULL context
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  5 06:53:55 iPhone SpringBoard[48] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jul  5 06:54:00 iPhone nehelper[97] <Error>: Configuration for provider com.apple.NetworkExtension.NetworkServiceProxy does not exist (<__NSConcreteUUID 0x16d14090> D727480A-72B9-430E-BF8F-9480304FA28D) or is not enabled (0)
Jul  5 06:54:00 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Error>: Probe message failed
Jul  5 06:55:00 iPhone wifid[74] <Error>: WiFi:[520955700.123604]: Disable WoW requested by "apsd"
Jul  5 06:57:22 iPhone UserEventAgent[23] <Error>: Could not get event name for stream/token: com.apple.backgroundtaskagent/45: 132: Request for stale data
   `
```

Crash Report:

```
{"bundleID":"com.apple.PassKit","app_name":"passd","share_with_app_devs":false,"name":"passd","app_version":"1.0","is_first_party":true,"os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)","slice_uuid":"d32v6729-2e4f-327b-9217-53b62kbb844f","bug_type":"109","build_version":"1","timestamp":"2017-07-05 06:44:05.05 -0700"}
Incident Identifier: AC0CE5BC-D198-4E5C-A9EF-979104BBA1FB
CrashReporter Key:   b68cdf2adc9e1b2b852dda7281b55628dfc2097a
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             passd [604]
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/PassKit.framework/passd
Identifier:          com.apple.PassKit
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2017-07-05 06:44:05.05 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-07-05 06:41:51.51 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x25cc7916 0x25462e12 0x25ccd2b0 0x25ccaedc 0x25bf6234 0x143e5a 0x13c73c 0x143ddc 0x136c60 0x2583f80e 0x2583580a 0x25843ba4 0x25c89b68 0x25c88062 0x25bd7224 0x25bd7010 0x26420040 0x2646ea48 0x104644 0x2587f86e)

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: you may have a testing issue if you are using the same serial with different authentication tokens - this is a long running bug.  If you are using different serials and authenticaion tokens for each path and you still have to toggle updates, check the console logs to see how the pass is originally registering.  The changeMessage goes in pass.json but will only trigger if the value for that key is different to the old pass already installed in the wallet.

Comment: @Passkit Thanks for your response. im giving unique serial numbers for each card and device token
Only thing im doing sending update request some time in 2 or 3 minutes it could be the problem ?  -- 2nd issue alert I did this but did not get alert  `{ "key": "memberid", "value": "", "label": "ID# 123456", "textAlignment" : "PKTextAlignmentLeft" } ], "backFields": [ { "label": "MOBILE TERMS:", "key": "info", "value" : "MOBILE TERMS ", changeMessage: "%@" } ]`   can you please verify im doing right ?

Comment: Console : `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Jun/2017:09:34:42 -0700] "GET /push.php HTTP/1.1" 200 188 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Jun/2017:09:34:43 -0700] "GET /v1/devices/af56c0d12bdbnf6kkatt3aa5c10d0dg64/registrations/‌​pass.test.com.mymobi‌​leDomain?passesUpdat‌​edSince=2017-06-30%2‌​009:23:06 HTTP/1.1" 200 68 `

Comment: The console logs should be from the iPhone (via Xcode).  What you have posted looks like your server logs.

Comment: “MOBILE” terms will need to change to a different value on the new pass if you want to trigger a change message

Comment: Your logs just show that a push was received on the device.  Need to see what happens after that (I.e. how Wallet or passd handles the request)

Comment: @PassKit i have question if you could answer ? please... im storing my pass-card.pkpass file in binary in DB when device request this code execute `if($result->rowCount() > 0) {` full code above in my post.  im missing something here ?

Comment: Just Updated log

Comment: did you fix this ? do you have the code? also do you know if you can send an updated pkpass zip file, as you were to send in an email, or just the .pkpass file ?

Comment: I did that but I'm not happy with results some time it does update most of the time doesn't

Comment: Look like u have signature issue .. I'm using same code what I was using first time create my pass file